# Vuejs- Error during redirecting in production mode

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I had created a project of vuejs using vue-cli 3 and it runs smoothly in development mode. When I created a build of it and runs, default entry page is shown(which is home.vue). But when i redirect to another page, it can't redirect and arises different console error on each page. Command used to run production build

> serve -s dist

One of the console error is shown below:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vue-router.esm.js:1905 Error: Loading chunk 3998 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:5000/default/dashboard/js/3998.e253d24e.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.c (bootstrap:176)
```

Here is my router file:

```
const Home = () => import('Views/pages/Home');
const About = () => import('Views/pages/About');
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: 'about',
            component: About
        },
      ]
   })
```

This is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import router from './router'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
 router,
 render: h => h(App),
 components: { App }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: I've never seen construction `const Home = () => import('Views/pages/Home')`. Why not use `import Home from 'Views/pages/Home'`?

Comment: @max Martynov this is used for lazy loading feature. You can read about lazyloading from given link https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html